# ghcjs-dom-hello world does not respond to mouse clicks - ghc 7.10.1

Tags: ghcjs, ghcjs-dom

I suppose this example should respond to mouse clicks: https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-dom-hello , right ? But when I try it with GHC 7.10.1 under Firefox and Chrome nothing happens when I click on the page.

Any ideas ? I haven't tried it with GHC 7.8.4 yet. But I will.

Answer (score 0):

One thing it could be is that ghcjs-dom-hello currently uses onclick on the body of the document.  Not all of the window will be clickable.  Try clicking on the Hello World text.

The new version of ghcjs-dom in github (currently requires the imporved-base version of ghcjs) includes document events (I left them out of the old version by mistake).  I'll update ghcjs-dom-hello to use them once improved-base is merged into master and the updated ghcjs-dom is in hackage.